# Spring Boot with Angularjs Logout Error

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, logout

I'm working with tutorial that describes how to write a modular Project single-page app using Spring Boot, Spring Security and AngularJS

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2-vanilla

and this Project

https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample

I cannot logout currently logged user.
If you click on the "logout" link you will see that the home page changes (the greeting is no longer displayed) so the user is no longer authenticated with the UI server. Click back on "login" though and you actually don’t need to go back through the authentication and approval cycle in the authorization server (because you haven’t logged out of that).

I'm new to Spring and would like that some User could logged out et come back to a login Page again.
Please somebody could help me or give some suggestion to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

it is our project code.its working fine for us. try this once.

security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("user")
                .and()
                .logout()
                // Logout requires form submit. Bypassing the same.
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html").and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable();/*
                                 * requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new
                                 * CsrfRequestMatcher())
                                 * .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
                                 */

    }
```

angularjs:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
                $http.get('/logout').then(function() {

                    $location.url('/');
                })
            }
```

routing:

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/admin', {
        templateUrl : 'admin.html',

    }).when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl : 'dashboard.html'
    }).when('/preferences', {
        templateUrl : 'preferences.html',
    }).otherwise('/', {
        templateUrl : 'index.html',
    })
} ]);
```

Comment: Hallo naresh vadlakonda,
thank you for your Answer, i try to use that but isnt solve my problem.
Please did you try to use in a github code link that i put on my problem description?
Thanks

Comment: Hello Naresh, If I need to make a post call for logout with CSRF Enabled, how can I do that? I'm getting a 406 - POST not supported when doing it with post method